# I have an array of string of mails, i want to make a data grid in WPF that contains 2 columns, mail column and checkbox column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datatable, datagrid

I need to create a datagrid in wpf that contains 2 columns, mail, and checkbox, after that I want the mails to show and a checkbox near them, I need a button that makes the following thing: all the checked checkboxes near the mail presented would get an email (i have that function)

I've tried to make a datatable with 2 columns, bool and string and present the mails there, my problem is that when i check the checkboxes near the mail i want to select, when i press the button and run on the datagrid rows, the boolean is still false instead of true and because of that that wont send the email

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="227" Margin="43,146,0,0" 
          VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="448" 
          Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Name="Datagrid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
     <DataGrid.Columns>
          <DataGridTextColumn Header="mails" Width="*" IsReadOnly="True" Binding="{Binding Path='Text'}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header ="send or not" Width="*">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Name="CheckboxMail"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

That's the datagrid.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Selected", typeof(bool))); //this will show checkboxes
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Text", typeof(string)));   //this will show text

Datagrid1.DataContext = dt;

foreach (string s in mails)
{
    DataRow r = dt.NewRow();
    r[0] = (bool)false;
    r[1] = s;
    dt.Rows.Add(r);
}

Datagrid1.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
```

Creation of the data table and the data grid

When I push the button:

```
foreach(DataRowView r in Datagrid1.ItemsSource)
{
    try
    {
        if(((Boolean)r[0]) == true)
        {
            MailMassage ms = new MailMassage((string)r[1]);
            ms.SendMail();
        }
    }
```

I expect the program to send an email to every mail in the datagrid that in its row there is a checked checkbox, thanks for the help.

Comment: please format your code

Comment: i dont know how to do this yet

Comment: @OBZ then you should read [ask] before posting here.

Comment: Where exactly is your problem? is `SendMail()` not working? Is accessing the data in the grid not working? Getting an Exception???

Comment: my problem is that when i check the checkboxes near the mail i want to select, when i press the button and run on the datagrid rows, the boolean is still false instead of true and becuase of that that wont send the email

Comment: How do you expect the `CheckBox` to know anything about the `DataRow`? They are not connected. Also invest time in learning MvvM. Other than that you will have to traverse visual tree of elements in the grid and then check the values of `CheckBoxes`.

Comment: so there isnt a way that i can select all the checked checkboxes in the datagrid, so why the hell there is a checkboxcollumn?

Comment: In WPF, it is expected that you data-bind a view model to controls. When you do this, the property you have bound to automatically changes to true/false based on the state of the checkbox. This is what Model-view-viewModel (MVVM) is for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind the `CheckBox` in the `CellEditingTemplate` to the `Selected` column:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header ="send or not" Width="*">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Selected}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Name="CheckboxMail" IsChecked="{Binding Selected}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: i tried that, the same problem is happening, after i check the checkbox when im pressing the foreach button its still shows that r[0] (which is the boolean) is false ;/

Comment: nevermind, its working tho, but i need to double click the cell in order to view the checkbox and then after i check it it returns to text and now its true, can i show the checkbox checked instead of that?

Answer (score 0):

You are binding Text but not Selected so your check isn't propogated to the datarowview.

You should bind IsChecked of your checkbox something like

```
 <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Selected}"/>
```

You might also need , mode=TwoWay on that binding.